# Automatically Run a Macro when a Cell is Changed in the Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm using a button to run the following macro and I am trying to have this macro run automatically when a cell is changed in the sheet.  I've found many other examples and I believe I have the right code for this but I am getting the error "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined".

Below is the first part macro:

```
Private Sub AutoCalc()
If Sheet1.Range("I5").Value = Sheet1.Range("D17").Value Then
Sheet1.Range("D18").Value = Sheet1.Range("H6").Value
Sheet1.Range("D19").Value = Sheet1.Range("H7").Value
Sheet1.Range("D20").Value = Sheet1.Range("H8").Value
Sheet1.Range("D21").Value = Sheet1.Range("H9").Value
Sheet1.Range("D22").Value = Sheet1.Range("H10").Value
Sheet1.Range("D23").Value = Sheet1.Range("H11").Value

ElseIf Sheet1.Range("I5").Value = Sheet1.Range("E17").Value Then
Sheet1.Range("E18").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheet1.Range("H6").Value, ChangingCell:=Sheet1.Range("D18")
Sheet1.Range("E19").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheet1.Range("H7").Value, ChangingCell:=Sheet1.Range("D19")
Sheet1.Range("E20").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheet1.Range("H8").Value, ChangingCell:=Sheet1.Range("D20")
Sheet1.Range("E21").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheet1.Range("H9").Value, ChangingCell:=Sheet1.Range("D21")
Sheet1.Range("E22").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheet1.Range("H10").Value, ChangingCell:=Sheet1.Range("D22")
Sheet1.Range("D23").Value = Sheet1.Range("H11").Value

End If
End Sub
```

And the second code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim InputCells As Range

Set InputCells = Range("Engine_Speed, Engine_Power, Exhaust_Temp, Exhaust_Flow, Engine_Combustion, 
Ref_O2, Water_Content, NOx_Input, CO_Input,NMHC_Input, VOC_Input, CH2O_Input, Oxygen_Input")

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), InputCells) Is Nothing Then

AutoCalc

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Private Sub AutoCalc()` ---> `Public Sub AutoCalc()`?

Comment: I feel quite dumb, needed to be Public Sub... Thank you

Comment: FYI `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as just `Target`